# ViewPager's PageAdapter get reset on orientation change

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using a `ViewPager` for a multiple-choice exam app, which chooses out randomly thirty questions out of a bigger set. I do this in the `PageAdapter` that is supplying the pages to the `ViewPager`.

The problem is that when an orientation change occurs, not only the pager but also the adapter gets reloaded - I know how to save the current pager position but when the adapter gets reset, it also chooses new questions from the set. What would be the proper way to handle this?

Also, side question - what would be the best way to register the choices on the RadioGroups? Directly by click or in a different way?

I'm fairly new to the Android app developement.

---

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        pager = new ViewPager(this);
        setContentView(pager);
        QuestionsAdapter adapter = new QuestionsAdapter(this);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        int position = 0;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Q_NUMBER");
        }         
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int position = pager.getCurrentItem();
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Q_NUMBER", position);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
class QuestionsAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    QuestionsHelper dbQuestions;
    boolean exam;
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> examQuestions;

    public QuestionsAdapter(Context context, boolean exam) {
        this.context = context;
        this.examQuestions = GetQuestionsFromDB(30);
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view;
        HashMap<String,Object> q;

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exam_question_layout, null);
        q = getQuestion(position+1);

        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.q_number)).setText(Integer.toString(position+1)+".");
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.q_question)).setText(q.get("question").toString());
        ((RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.q_answer_a)).setText(q.get("answer_a").toString());
        ((RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.q_answer_b)).setText(q.get("answer_b").toString());
        ((RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.q_answer_c)).setText(q.get("answer_c").toString());

        ((ViewPager)collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, I know I could lock the orientation but I rather wouldn't limit the user to a single orientation.

Comment: you could retrieve your 'examQuestions' list in onSaveInstanceState, store them, and then in onCreate you try to retrieve this list. If the list isn't empty you pass it into the adapter and use that

Comment: @dymmeh But I don't think I can save the whole `List<HashMap<String,Object>>`, can I? I could of course save just an array of the IDs but I don't think it's very efficient to query the database again just becuase the orientation has changed.

Comment: You could always create a "Question" object which is Parcelable. This object will contain everything you have in your current map (question, answer_a/b/c, db ID). Your adapter will contain a list of questions (List<Question>). Then in onSaveInstanceState you can pass your parcelable array list to the saved instance.

Comment: I guess I'll have to read more about the `Parcelable` interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know how to save the current pager position but when the adapter
>   gets reset, it also chooses new questions from the set. What would be
>   the proper way to handle this?

Your questions should really have an `id` to uniquely identify them. I'm not sure how you get them from the database but when that would happen you would need to store their ids. Also:

- Your adapter should have a `long` array(or integer) holding 30 values representing the ids of the current selected batch of questions
- You'll need to implement the following logic in the adapter: if the long array from the previous point is `null` then assume it's a clean start and get a new set of 30 questions. 
  If the long array is non null then we are facing a restore from a configuration change and you'll need to use those ids to get the proper questions from the database instead of a random batch
- In the `Activity` you'll save the long array of the adapter in the `onSaveInstanceState()` method(`savedInstanceState.putLongArray`)
- In the `onCreate` method of the `Activity`, when you create the adapter, you'll check the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle` to see if it is non-null and it has the long array and set that on the adapter(so it will know which questions to get)

> what would be the best way to register the choices on the RadioGroups?
>   Directly by click or in a different way?

You could use the above method, or create a custom class with `Parcelable` like it has already been recommended to you in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would storing all the 30 questions as Parcelable object be wrong approach? Instead of just the IDs (and yes, I have unique ids in the DB).

Comment: @Czechnology *Would storing all the 30 questions as Parcelable object be wrong approach?* - No, as you just need to store an id + some small status values in that class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response - I've created a Question class implementing the Parcelable interface - it saves all the data to Parcel. As dymmeh suggested in the comments. Not just the id.

Comment: @Czechnology I was thinking of storing only the minimum amount of data required to setup those questions, but you could make the whole Question as `Parcelable` with no problem.

Comment: That's the thing - is there a limit or a best practice guideline of how much data should one store in an instance? Are 30 saved questions with three answers better than repeated DB query?

Comment: @Czechnology Of course there are some limits(if I'm not mistaken is 1MB of data). There also aren't any best practices, you just need to make sure you pass the smallest amount of data required at the receiver end to use it(that is way I recommended saving only the id and current checked item). But in your case(depending on what the question consists) you most likely could get away with making that whole question class `Parcelable`. Even if you need to make the database queries this shouldn't be a problem(use background threads, use placeholders until the question is loaded etc)

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, I'll bear them in mind! Currently, I've saved it all, the questions and answers aren't so long.

Answer (score 12):

Screen Rotation will redraw the entire screen in the new orientation, we can prevent it with overriding configuration changes.

add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" under your screen declaration in Android Manifest

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

And Override onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) in your activity like

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
```

Comment: I havent used it on SherlockActivity, but had I assume it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, I know this possibility exists but it's more of a quick fix, not a correct standard solution.

Comment: Not working when i have Activity->Fragment->Viewpager