# Wrong page in ViewPager after screen change

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a problem with restoring proper ViewPager page after orientation change.

**CONCEPT:**

I've got ViewPager which is set for 8 pages initially.

It has OnPageCHangeListener and when user reaches 5th page, I fetch data from server and add another 8 pages to ViewPager.

So every 7 pages I add another 8 pages, it makes it endless. This is listener code:

```
      ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.frame);
      mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

            if(arg0 % 7) {
                addPagesToViewPagerAdapter(isMainPage);
            }

        }
```

This is my ViewPager adapter code:

```
public class FullImageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private static ArrayList<Main> response;

public FullImageAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm,
        ArrayList<Main> resp) {
    super(fm);
    response = resp;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return response.size();
}
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return FullImageFragment.newInstance(response.get(position));
}

public void addPages(ArrayList<Main> resp) {
    response.addAll(resp);
}
```

}

I also has onConfigurationChaged in Activity which holds ViewPager fragment.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

Problem is with showing proper ViewAdapter page when orientation change.

For example:

At the beggining there are 8 pages in the ViewPager.

User scrolles to the 3rd page, then change orientation and 3rd page is shown. Everything works fine.

Problem is when uses scrolls after 8 pages f.ex to the 9th (at that time there are 16 pages, because at page 7th we added 8 more) when he change orientation at 9th, the 8th page is shown, which is bad.

To sum up:

Changing orientation:

- At position 3 - shown is 3 - good
- At position 7 - shown is 7 - good
- At position 8 - shown is 8 - good
- At position 9  - shown is 8 -BAD
- At position 10 - shown is 8 - BAD
- etc.

It seems like whatever is handling orientation changes doesn't know that I added more pages and it's showing the last page that was in the adapter at the beggining.

This only affects changing orientation, when user scrolls "normally" everything is fine.
I also use diffrent layouts for land and horizontal orientation.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Consider the following link this may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323905/viewpagers-pageadapter-get-reset-on-orientation-change

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't solve my problem. I'm dynamically adding pages to my adapter. And I guess, I have to somehow add it to savedinstancestate.